Polars arithmetic operation using a boolean mask and different sized array
I tried so hard with ChatGPT but couldn't make this work and it couldn't solve it either. How am I supposed to assign or increment set of values using a boolean mask? This is what I was doing with pandas.
validation_predictions = model.predict(validation_dataset)
df.loc[validation_mask, 'prediction'] += validation_predictions / len(seeds)

validation_mask has N number of True and validation_predictions is a numpy array of size N, so an assignment like this works fine. However I couldn't achieve the same thing with polars.
I tried when/then/otherwise chain but it throws an error since validation_predictions size doesn't match with entire dataframe's size.
df = df.with_columns(
    pl.when(validation_mask)
    .then(pl.col('prediction') + (validation_predictions / len(seeds)))
    .otherwise(pl.col('prediction'))
    .alias('prediction')
)
# ShapeError: cannot evaluate two Series of different lengths (6 and 5)

For reproducibility purposes:
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

seeds = [42, 1337, 0]

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "some_column": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
    "prediction": [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
})

validation_mask = df["some_column"] > 15
validation_predictions = np.array([0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5])

Expected result:
shape: (6, 2)
┌─────────────┬────────────┐
│ some_column ┆ prediction │
│ ---         ┆ ---        │
│ i64         ┆ f64        │
╞═════════════╪════════════╡
│ 10          ┆ 1.0        │
│ 20          ┆ 2.166667   │
│ 30          ┆ 3.5        │
│ 40          ┆ 4.833333   │
│ 50          ┆ 6.166667   │
│ 60          ┆ 7.5        │
└─────────────┴────────────┘


Could you provide a MRE?

Added a small snippet for reproducible example

seeds needs to be added to complete the example.

@jqurious sorry I didn't include it since it was trivial. Added it right now.

No problem. It's just that people will downvote if the example requires any modifications in order to run it.

The array of validation_predictions is too small. I assume that this array will always be the length of (df.filter('condition').
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

seeds = [42, 1337, 0]

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "some_column": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
        "prediction": [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0],
    }
)

validation_mask = df["some_column"] > 15
validation_predictions = np.array([0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5])

assert sum(validation_mask) == len(validation_predictions)

# extend the validation predictions:
new_arr = np.empty(len(df))
new_arr[:] = np.nan
new_arr[validation_mask] = validation_predictions

df = df.with_columns(
    pl.when(validation_mask)
    .then(pl.col("prediction") + (new_arr / len(seeds)))
    .otherwise(pl.col("prediction"))
    .alias("prediction")
)

With this method the validation predictions is extended with nans.

Even though this is kinda counter-intuitive, I'm accepting this. The other answer was less efficient since it was adding an index and joining on that.

Use df.with_row_index to get the original positions, filter based on that, then perform a Join.
If you use a inner join (the default) it'll drop the rows filtered out, but you can use a left join then coalesce using fill_null
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "some_column": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
    "prediction": [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
})
validation_mask = df["some_column"] > 15
validation_predictions = np.array([0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5])

df = df.with_row_index('idx')

positions = df.select(pl.col("idx").filter(validation_mask))

val_predictions = positions.with_columns(val_prediction = validation_predictions)

joined = df.join(val_predictions, on="idx", how="left")
result = joined.with_columns(pl.col("prediction") + pl.col("val_prediction").fill_null(0)).drop('val_prediction')

print(result)


If you create a column containing the indices, you can wrap the array with pl.lit() which allows you to use expressions on it, e.g. .get()
when/then + .cum_sum() is one way to create such a column.
validation_mask = pl.col.some_column > 15
validation_idxs = pl.when(validation_mask).then(1).cum_sum() - 1

df.with_columns(
   pl.coalesce(
       pl.col.prediction + (
           pl.lit(validation_predictions).get(validation_idxs) / len(seeds)
       ),
       pl.col.prediction # use original value if idx is null
   )
)

shape: (6, 2)
┌─────────────┬────────────┐
│ some_column ┆ prediction │
│ ---         ┆ ---        │
│ i64         ┆ f64        │
╞═════════════╪════════════╡
│ 10          ┆ 1.0        │
│ 20          ┆ 2.166667   │
│ 30          ┆ 3.5        │
│ 40          ┆ 4.833333   │
│ 50          ┆ 6.166667   │
│ 60          ┆ 7.5        │
└─────────────┴────────────┘

pl.coalesce() (or fill_null) is used to combine the null/non-null values into a single column.
Here's the individual steps broken down into columns.
(df.with_columns(idx = validation_idxs)
   .with_columns(value = pl.lit(validation_predictions).get(pl.col.idx))
   .with_columns(new = pl.col.prediction + (pl.col.value / len(seeds)))
   .with_columns(result = pl.coalesce(pl.col.new, pl.col.prediction))
)  

shape: (6, 6)
┌─────────────┬────────────┬──────┬───────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ some_column ┆ prediction ┆ idx  ┆ value ┆ new      ┆ result   │
│ ---         ┆ ---        ┆ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ i64         ┆ f64        ┆ i32  ┆ f64   ┆ f64      ┆ f64      │
╞═════════════╪════════════╪══════╪═══════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ 10          ┆ 1.0        ┆ null ┆ null  ┆ null     ┆ 1.0      │
│ 20          ┆ 2.0        ┆ 0    ┆ 0.5   ┆ 2.166667 ┆ 2.166667 │
│ 30          ┆ 3.0        ┆ 1    ┆ 1.5   ┆ 3.5      ┆ 3.5      │
│ 40          ┆ 4.0        ┆ 2    ┆ 2.5   ┆ 4.833333 ┆ 4.833333 │
│ 50          ┆ 5.0        ┆ 3    ┆ 3.5   ┆ 6.166667 ┆ 6.166667 │
│ 60          ┆ 6.0        ┆ 4    ┆ 4.5   ┆ 7.5      ┆ 7.5      │
└─────────────┴────────────┴──────┴───────┴──────────┴──────────┘


Thanks for the reply. It looks like polars is not good with this kind of operations. I don't know what is this called maybe "inplace assignment" but whatever. All of the solutions are some kind of workaround and they increased the memory footprint of my pipeline. I had to switch to pandas because of that.

Yes, in Polars a column (Series) (arrow memory) is "immutable". https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/17728#issuecomment-2243053669 so there is no real inplace assignment.
